# ArrayAdapter inside Tablayout using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

So basically I am trying to have an ArrayAdapter inside a Fragment to be used on a TabLayout

```
public class fragment_restaurants extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_restaurants, container, false);

        ArrayList<InformationModel> hotelList = new ArrayList<>();

        hotelList.add(new InformationModel("Copacabana Palace", "Copacabana", "215"));
        hotelList.add(new InformationModel("Copacabana Resort", "Botafogo", "589"));
        hotelList.add(new InformationModel("Sarrada Motel", "Bangu", "105"));
        hotelList.add(new InformationModel("5 Estrelas da Oi", "Centro", "669"));
        hotelList.add(new InformationModel("Pereira Cardoso", "Saramamduba", "123"));
        hotelList.add(new InformationModel("Sepetiba Palace", "Sepetiba", "774"));
        hotelList.add(new InformationModel("Copacabana Palace", "Copacabana", "215"));
        hotelList.add(new InformationModel("Copacabana Resort", "Botafogo", "589"));
        hotelList.add(new InformationModel("Sarrada Motel", "Bangu", "105"));
        hotelList.add(new InformationModel("5 Estrelas da Oi", "Centro", "669"));
        hotelList.add(new InformationModel("Pereira Cardoso", "Saramamduba", "123"));
        hotelList.add(new InformationModel("Sepetiba Palace", "Sepetiba", "774"));

        InformationAdapter adapter = new InformationAdapter(mContext, hotelList);
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewTabRestaurants);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
}
```

I am having this error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: com.example.rick.tourapp, PID: 4616
>                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.Object
>   android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null
>   object reference

How do I solve this? Should I make another class with this array adapter already done and initialize inside this fragment subclass?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code seems like your `mContext` is null

Initialize it :

```
mContext = getActivity();
```